# Post Request to service endpoint with dictonary with nested subdictionary.RobotFrameowork

Tags: python-requests, robotframework

I am having a service definition (Rest) and I want to execute POST Request lavereging RequestsLibrary in Robot Frameowrk . Problem is with service itself which is design to accept dictionary with subdictionary. Do you find it feasible to even create such Post method ?

Service defintion accepting following structure. I am creating following keyword to orchestrate that :

```
PostRequestAPI
    Create Session    ${AliasName}    ${PostReqURL}   auth=${Authen}
    ${head}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json        Authorization=Basic c3U6Z3c=
    ${resp}=    Post Request    ${AliasName}      ${PostReqURI}    data={"payload":{"BatchFeeAmount":10, "NonCollectableFeeAmount':11,"FileID":"234324324322"},"header":{"saveDate":"2019-07-17T16:37:22.123Z" }}  headers=${head}    # (edited) 
   ${resp} = Response [400] [Expected service definition ]
```

Picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSTle.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. There are 2 ways:

`Method 1:` You have 2 dictionaries, `payload` and `header`, that you want to use as key-value pair in a third dictionary. If you go step by step, the below is the code you will end up with:

```
Dictionary of dictionary 
    ${payload}  Create Dictionary  BatchFeeAmount=10  NonCollectableFeeAmount=11  FileID=234324324322  
    ${header}   Create Dictionary  saveDate=2019-07-17T16:37:22.123Z
    ${data}     Create Dictionary  payload=${payload}  header=${header}

    Log To Console  ${data}
    // ${data} contains the API POST request payload in your desired format
```

`Method 2:` You can also define your nested dictionary as a pure python variable and then use that file in your robot script. Like below:

variables.py

```
data ={"payload":{"BatchFeeAmount":10,  "NonCollectableFeeAmount":11,  "FileID":234324324322}, "header":{"saveDate":"2019-07-17T16:37:22.123Z"}}
```

test_case.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Variables  /path/to/variables.py

*** Test Cases ***
Dictionary of Dictionaries
    Log to Console    ${data}
```